# DMZ account app pool identity from web server to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, asp.net-identity, impersonation, application-pool

We have a very strange problem on our production web app. Our web application is external facing and uses impersonation for app pool identity using a DMZ account. However randomly we see our application crashing while the user trying to login to the application. We get an exception as shown below-

As you can see when the authenticate method is called we get a failure indicating:

**Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:

Thread account name: DMZ account**

It appears as though the SQL Server does not allow the asp.net app pool identity to connect randomly, which is the DMZ account. Now this happens intermittently , not always. The asp.net application impersonates as pool identity, however it connects to SQL Server via a SQL login.

**The weirdest thing is if we connect to production sever from Visual Studio, it connects to the same production SQL Server ok and the production site magically starts working ! It's almost as if the local domain account that Visual Studio impersonated as unlocked the production DMZ account.**

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at eCertsFormsAdmin.ControllerBase.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: https://appurl:443/Home/Authenticate?param={'AccessCode' :'demo', 'UserName' :'user'} 
    Request path: /Home/Authenticate 
    User host address: web server ip address 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: DMZ account 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 5 
    Thread account name: DMZ account
    Is impersonating: True 
    Stack trace:    at eCertsFormsAdmin.ControllerBase.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details: 

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-03-28T13:56:18.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>425417</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Web server</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3005</Data>
    <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
    <Data>3/28/2017 9:56:18 AM</Data>
    <Data>3/28/2017 1:56:18 PM</Data>
    <Data>3accff4bebb74aa5823c9d05fe7ae5c0</Data>
    <Data>135</Data>
    <Data>4</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT-1-131351820594338174</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/</Data>
    <Data>C:\www\apppath\</Data>
    <Data>Web server</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>6768</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>GTSDMZ\eValid</Data>
    <Data>NullReferenceException</Data>
    <Data>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at eCertsFormsAdmin.ControllerBase.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass25.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1d.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)

</Data>
    <Data>https://appurl:443/Home/Authenticate?param={'AccessCode' :'demo', 'UserName' :'user', }</Data>
    <Data>/Home/Authenticate</Data>
    <Data>server ip</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>DMZ account</Data>
    <Data>5</Data>
    <Data>DMZ account</Data>
    <Data>True</Data>
    <Data>   at OurApp.ControllerBase.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass25.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1d.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Our Environment:

**Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise
IIS 7.5
Web server is in DMZ**

Comment: it seems you are facing login issues randomly,for every login failure,sql server logs a message into error log by default.Can you check that and paste it

Comment: We ran SQL Profiler on Prod SQL server.  All we see is Entity Framework doing a Database Initialization. After that rest of the queries are not executed. Does that help...

Comment: The infrastructure were unable to find any entries in SQL logs

Comment: Probably related: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)